# Powershell in azure portal : This module requires Az.Accounts version 2.12.5. earlier version of Az.Accounts is imported in current PowerShell session

Tags: azure, powershell, module

Requesting a Cloud Shell.Succeeded.
Connecting terminal...

```
Import-Module: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:13
Line |
  13 |  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Import-Module -Name PSCloudShellUtility
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | This module requires Az.Accounts version 2.12.5. An earlier version of Az.Accounts is imported in the current PowerShell session. Please open a new session before importing this
     | module. This error could indicate that multiple incompatible versions of the Azure PowerShell cmdlets are installed on your system. Please see https://aka.ms/azps-version-error for
     | troubleshooting information.
Import-Module: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:26
Line |
  26 |  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Import-Module Az.Tools.Predictor -Force
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Assembly with same name is already loaded
InvalidOperation: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:308
Line |
 308 |  & ($script:PSCloudShellUtilityModuleInfo){Get-CloudShellTip -ErrorAct …
     |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
VERBOSE: Authenticating to Azure ...
InvalidOperation: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:64
Line |
  64 |      & ($script:PSCloudShellUtilityModuleInfo){param([string]$Label, [ …
     |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
Invoke-CloudShellTelemetry: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:95
Line |
  95 |          Invoke-CloudShellTelemetry -LogLabel "GETSUBSCRIPTIONID" -Sta …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
InvalidOperation: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:64
Line |
  64 |      & ($script:PSCloudShellUtilityModuleInfo){param([string]$Label, [ …
     |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
InvalidOperation: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:64
Line |
  64 |      & ($script:PSCloudShellUtilityModuleInfo){param([string]$Label, [ …
     |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
InvalidOperation: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:64
Line |
  64 |      & ($script:PSCloudShellUtilityModuleInfo){param([string]$Label, [ …
     |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
Import-Module: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:395
Line |
 395 |      Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Import-Module -Name AzurePSDrive
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | This module requires Az.Accounts version 2.12.5. An earlier version of Az.Accounts is imported in the current PowerShell session. Please open a new session before importing this
     | module. This error could indicate that multiple incompatible versions of the Azure PowerShell cmdlets are installed on your system. Please see https://aka.ms/azps-version-error for
     | troubleshooting information.
VERBOSE: Building your Azure drive ...
InvalidOperation: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:64
Line |
  64 |      & ($script:PSCloudShellUtilityModuleInfo){param([string]$Label, [ …
     |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
New-PSDrive: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:406
Line |
 406 |      $null = Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\New-PSDrive -Name Azure - …
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find a provider with the name 'SHiPS'.
WARNING: Something went wrong while creating Azure drive. You can still use this shell to run Azure PowerShell commands.
InvalidOperation: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:64
Line |
  64 |      & ($script:PSCloudShellUtilityModuleInfo){param([string]$Label, [ …
     |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
InvalidOperation: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:419
Line |
 419 |  & ($script:PSCloudShellUtilityModuleInfo){Set-CloudShellPSReadLineKey …
     |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
InvalidOperation: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/profile.ps1:64
Line |
  64 |      & ($script:PSCloudShellUtilityModuleInfo){param([string]$Label, [ …
     |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
PS /home/kumari> Get-Module Az.Accounts

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Script     2.9.1                 Az.Accounts                         {Add-AzEnvironment, Clear-AzConfig, Clear-AzContext, Clear-AzDefault…}

PS /home/user> update-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 2.12.5
Install-Package: Unable to find repository '/usr/cloudshell/temp'. Use Get-PSRepository to see all available repositories.
```

Answer (score 2):

***Error cause:*** If a version of `Az.Accounts` has already been loaded in a PowerShell session, that version cannot be replaced with an updated version, and it is clearly detailed in [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/documentation/troubleshoot-module-load.md#symptom-error-when-importing-an-azure-powershell-module) doc.

***Need to check below:***

To verify the installed `Az.accounts` versions in the current `Powershell` module, use

```
Get-InstalledModule Az.Accounts -AllVersions
```

It displays all the loaded versions in the output as shown. Now In the `PSModulePath`, identify multiple entries for `Az.Accounts` in different directories.

[image]

If you see any older versions in the output data, just remove the ones that are not in the global scope `%ProgramFiles%PowerShellModules`. Modules can be removed just deleting the module directory by visiting the path `C:user>DocumentsPowerShellModulesAz.Accounts`.

More detailed information in [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/documentation/troubleshoot-module-load.md#potential-reason-1-older-version-stored-in-user-or-global-scope) doc.

***And***

While installing or importing the module, use `-RequiredVersion` flag. So that the `PowerShell` session takes the current module version data and executes it accordingly.

```
Import-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 2.12.5
```

Check the latest versions of modules data in [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Accounts/2.12.5).

*If still the issue persists, close the current* `PowerShell` *session and run the cmdlets again.*

You can also check here for [incompatibilities](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/documentation/troubleshoot-module-load.md#why-are-incompatibilities-possible) issues in a brief way.

Comment: Used the command provided in answer but cannot find the path to delete
PS /home/username> Get-InstalledModule Az.Accounts -AllVersions
Version              Name                    Repository        Description
-------              ----                          ----------           -----------
2.12.5               Az.Accounts            /usr/cloudshell/temp Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Accounts credential management cmdlets for Azure RM  
2.9.1                Az.Accounts             PSGallery            Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Accounts credential management cmdlets for Azure RM

Comment: Path for `Get-InstalledModule` are you saying? @Talang_madave

Comment: Are you able to find the path? @Talang_madave

Comment: to remove a module just delete its directory, for example using  "rm /home/<your-user>/.local/share/powershell/Modules/Az.Accounts -r